# Change CPT permalink to use the category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a CPT called teachers and a custom taxonomy called teacher type.

I'm using the code below to rewrite the url for the CPT and instead of being like: website.com/teachers/post1

it changes the slug to use the category: website.com/teacher-type/post1

This is working correctly but now I need to add another taxonomy (year) to the CPT and to the slug and I need it to be like this:

website.com/teacher-type/year/post1

The code I'm using is compatible with WPML.

This is it:

```
    function resources_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    global $sitepress, $sitepress_settings;

    $has_filter = remove_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ) );
    $auto_adjust_ids = $sitepress_settings['auto_adjust_ids'];
    $sitepress_settings['auto_adjust_ids'] = 0;

    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'teacher_types',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $post_type = 'teachers';

    foreach ($terms as $term) {    

        $rules[ $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&name=$matches[1]';

    }

    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

    if ( $has_filter ) {
        add_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ) );
    }
    $sitepress_settings['auto_adjust_ids'] = $auto_adjust_ids;

}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'resources_cpt_generating_rule', 20);

function change_link( $permalink, $post ) {

    if( $post->post_type == 'teachers' ) {
        $resource_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'teacher_types' );
        $term_slug = '';
        if( ! empty( $resource_terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $resource_terms as $term ) {
                // The featured resource will have another category which is the main one

                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                break;
            }
        }
        $permalink = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', trailingslashit( get_home_url() ) . $term_slug . '/' . $post->post_name );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link',"change_link",10,2);
```

Any ideas on how to concatenate those two taxonomies in the url?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update below line at where you have register a custom post type using register_post_type function.

**`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'teachers/%cat%')`**

To change permalink dynamically of post type you have to add below code in functions.php file :

```
function change_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array('teacher-type','year') );
        if ( $terms ) {
            return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
        }
    }

    return  apply_filters('wpml_permalink', $post_link );
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_link', 1, 3 );

//load the template on the new generated URL otherwise you will get 404's the page

function generated_rewrite_rules() {

   add_rewrite_rule(
       '^teachers/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
       'index.php?post_type=teachers&name=$matches[2]',
       'top'
   );
}
add_action( 'init', 'generated_rewrite_rules' );
```

After that, you need to flush rewrites permalinks, goto the **wp-admin > Settings >  permalinks**. just update permalink setting using "Save Changes" button.

it'll return urls like below :

- website.com/teachers/teacher-type/post1
- website.com/teachers/year/post1

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help vaghela, but I'm afraid that this method doesn't work for me. I need it to have both taxonomies in the url and delete the custom post type name: website.com/teacher-type/year/post1